# Can't save to Neo4j database

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I am trying to create a Spring Boot project with Neo4j. I connected successfully with Neo4j. But when I save data to Neo4j, it has error. Below is my project:

User:

[image]

UserRepository:
[image]
User Controller:
[image]
UserService:
[image]

And when I call API signup to save user to Neo4j. It has error in UserService at line "userRepository.save(user);". Here is it:
[image]

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you by chance created two users in your database with the same id?

Can you please check that? A good way to avoid that is to

```
create constraint on (u:User) assert u.id is unique;
```

Comment: oh. thank you so much. I solved my problem!